# What has happened to Queen Izanami?

Tags: vertigo-comics, lucifer

When Lucifer returned to the realm of Izanami-no-Mikoto, instead of a stone statue of big, fat woman, he met a lovely young queen, that proceeded to seduce him. When Lucifer left after a night of passion, Izanami called her maids, artisans and goldsmiths and then she stepped into molten gold:

**<sup>warning, a picture of boobs below</sup>**

> [image: Queen of creation and death in the nude]

And then she proceeds to create (or rather turn herself into)... something, seemingly taking power from her tryst with Lucifer

[image]

What has she turned herself into? Another statue of fat woman? Is this story arc continued anywhere else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right, this story continues - in the [2015 continuation of the comic](http://www.vertigocomics.com/comics/lucifer-2015), written first by Holly Black and then by Richard Kadrey.

Izanami bore a child - Lucifer's son, Takehiko; she was planning to make her son the ruler of Hell (apart from being the heir to her own realm), not to mention her personal vendetta against Lucifer.

[image]
 <sub>*Lucifer* (2016) #6</sub>

[image]
 <sub>*Lucifer* (2016) #7</sub>

If you want to know how it ended,

> they failed. Surprise!

Comment: 15 years waiting to fix a plothole? Geez!

Comment: @Yasskier Plot hole? I disagree - it was deliberately left open, same as some other things from the original series. In fact, I'd pretty much prefer this new series not to happen - it had some nice moments, but overall it felt hopelessly out of place, while still trying to continue Carey's plot (and failing). And they didn't even "fix" anything - the villains retreated, so it's obvious they'd be back. And it seems that this run is over too - no issues after #19, which I think is for the good.

Comment: Lets agree to disagree :) For me it was looking as something that was left open to be used SOON (or in spin-off), but because of executive meddling was forgotten. Waiting 15 years to show what was inside the "bottle" is bit too long, especially since the original Lucifer series looks like a closed story to me.

Comment: @Yasskier Carey planned to end his run on the 75th issue, so this was intentional, that's for sure. And the end of his run can be read in a very meta way - e.g. in your second picture, when Izanami says "I understand the need for continuity", it can be read as coming directly from Carey - he understood that the series _might_ get a continuation, and thus left some seeds for it. Regardless, I think the new writers could have used Carey's legacy better.